# extract multiple values from a free text column in a cvs file

Tags: r, nlp, extract

I have a CVS file with a column that consists of a series of medical tests, in free text, with the date, the test names and results, like it follows.
I need to extract the values of each of those medical tests and turn them into columns.
I would like to know if there is a way of doing it without having to train a model of NLP to extract those information.

| Patient | Results |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" |
| 2 | "06/01/2022 - ALT/TGP: 25.0 06/01/2022 - AST/TGO: 40.0 06/03/2022 - Bilirrubin: 0.8" |
| 3 | "01/03/2022 - HMG - Haematocrit: 40 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 10.2" |

CSV:

```
Patient;Results 
1;"01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" 
2;"06/01/2022 - ALT/TGP: 25.0 06/01/2022 - AST/TGO: 40.0 06/03/2022 - Bilirrubin: 0.8" 
3;"01/03/2022 - HMG - Haematocrit: 40 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 10.2"
```

Comment: This table was taken from the file itself. I have edited to add them as they are in the cvs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `DF` is defined reproducibly as in the Note at the end insert a newline before each date, separate into distinct rows, separate the Date and Test and then the Test and Value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(Results = gsub(" (../../....)", "\n\\1", Results)) %>%
  separate_rows(Results, sep = "\n") %>%
  separate(Results, c("Date", "Test"), sep = " - ", extra = "merge") %>%
  separate(Test, c("Test", "Value"), sep = ": ", convert = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  Patient Date       Test                Value
    <int> <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>
1       1 01/03/2022 HMG - Plaques     65000  
2       1 01/03/2022 HMG - Haemoglobin     7.8
3       1 01/05/2022 Urea                 50  
4       1 01/05/2022 HMG - Plaques     80000  
5       2 06/01/2022 ALT/TGP              25  
6       2 06/01/2022 AST/TGO              40  
7       2 06/03/2022 Bilirrubin            0.8
8       3 01/03/2022 HMG - Haematocrit    40  
9       3 01/03/2022 HMG - Haemoglobin    10.2
```

### Note

```
Lines <- 'Patient;Results 
1;"01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" 
2;"06/01/2022 - ALT/TGP: 25.0 06/01/2022 - AST/TGO: 40.0 06/03/2022 - Bilirrubin: 0.8" 
3;"01/03/2022 - HMG - Haematocrit: 40 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 10.2"'
DF <- read.csv2(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions (regex). If you're doing it in R the `stringr` package is great for that. If you wanted to extract all the dates, you could do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr) # for pipes

"01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" %>%
str_extract_all("[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}")
```

If you want to extract everything between the first and second date (not including the dates), you could do something like this:

```
"01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" %>%
  str_extract("(?<=[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}).*?(?=[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4})")
```

To remove everything starting with the first date (inclusive) up to the second date (non-inclusive) you could do something like this:

```
"01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" %>%
  str_extract("[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}.*?(?=[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4})")
```

You could save that extracted text and then remove it from the larger string doing something like this:

```
first_result <- "01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" %>%
  str_extract("[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}.*?(?=[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4})")

"01/03/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 65000 01/03/2022 - HMG - Haemoglobin: 7.8 01/05/2022 - Urea: 50.0 01/05/2022 - HMG - Plaques: 80000" %>%
  str_remove(first_result)
```

You could do a series of these extractions until you have all the results broken into individual tests. Once you have that, the test names and values could also be extracted with similiar regular expressions. For example:

```
first_date <- first_result %>% str_extract("[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}")
first_test_name <- first_result %>% str_extract("(?<=-).*(?=:)")
first_result_value <- first_result %>% str_extract("(?<=:).*")
```

The stringr package also works on vectors/dataframe columns. For example:

```
c("a2bc","dfr4","5qwer") %>% str_extract("[0-9]")
```

`str_extract_all()` returns a list, so that needs to be accounted for. Depending on what you need sometimes the easiest thing to do is just use `unlist()` to convert the list of extracted values to a vector.

Extra white space can be removed using `str_squish()`. There are a ton of other functions in the `stringr` package and other things that can be done with regular expressions depending on what sort of format you want the data to eventually be in. There are probably more efficient ways to do what I did with slightly more complicated look-around patterns. You can also do similar things to what the `stringr` package does with base r using `sub()` and `gsub()`.

There are a bunch of regex resources online and Stack overflow has a bunch of regex questions and answers too!